# UITextField's clearbutton is not working in the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` that has some cells and I add a `UITextField` to each of the cells.

I set `textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing`.

When I am editing the textField, the clear button and the keyboard both come out. I type some words in the textField, then tap the clear button, the keyboard will be hidden but the text in the textField will not be cleared.

All of the others work well except the clear button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this problem because I had forgotten I was using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to catch taps on the table to dismiss the keyboard and it was capturing the tap on the clear button, preventing it from functioning. Add `cancelsTouchesInView=NO` on the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to let the touches still take effect and check using `CGRectContainsPoint` on the tapper method to only end editing and `resignFirstResponder` only when the tap wasn't on the current `UITextField`'s frame rect. Note that this still isn't totally perfect since tapping X on an autocorrect might be outside the text field's frame rect, so maybe checking the cell's `contentView` would be better.

Comment: the same with you, I was also using a UITapGestureRecognizer to catch taps on the table. Thanks

Comment: Where should the cancelsTouchesInView=NO be performed? In the tap method?

Comment: A more complete example would be nice ;-)

Comment: @JohanKarlsson It's a property of the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 3):

if you have got gesture Recogniser you should do like this way

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(methodThatYouMayCall)];
[myTextField addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
gestureRecognizer.delegate =  self;
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

and this will clear textfield as well as fires "methodThatYouMayCall" when you click on the clear button so that you should do this as well
your textField.clearButtonMode is kind of UIButton class, so that you can do this way

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{   
   if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
   {
       return NO;
   }
   else
   {
       return YES;
   }
}
```

don't forget mark the class as implementing the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.
hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce the issue you are having, since touching the Clear button does not and should not resign the first responder. But perhaps you can compare your code to the most basic use case I included below in order to find what went wrong.

Additionally, I would recommend reading the documentation about [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) since it seems like you may be accidentally dabbling in this area.

```
@implementation TextFieldTableViewController

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // Remove old instances of myTextField
    for (UIView *oldView in cell.contentView.subviews)
        [oldView removeFromSuperview];

    // Create my new text field
    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
    [myTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    [myTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

    // Add the TextField to the content view
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myTextField];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

While the original issue was not caused by this, I think any future searches that lead here may need to know:

Views you add to a `UITableViewCell` **must** be added as subviews to its `contentView` property, otherwise you may experience the views being displayed with no user interactions enabled.

You have been supposed to add subviews to `contentView` since iOS 2.0.